# Update the device time from another App not from System App

Tags: android, date, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

Hi I am building one Android App.which takes input from user in DatePicker and TimePicker and  set the Device Time or Modile Time.

This is the code I am using

```
            int     nHrTime;
    int     nMinTime;
    int     nYear;

    int nMonth;
    int nDay;

    nHrTime     =  DeviceTimePickr.getCurrentHour();
    nMinTime    =  DeviceTimePickr.getCurrentMinute();

    nYear   =  DeviceDatePickr.getYear();
    nMonth      =  DeviceDatePickr.getMonth();
    nDay        =  DeviceDatePickr.getDayOfMonth();

    dDeviceCalendar.set(nYear, nMonth,nDay,nHrTime, nMinTime);
```

In manifest.xml file I hve chanes the permission also.

Changes in manifest file

```
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature|system"/>
```

Why this not working? I am using android 4.22

Answer (score 0):

Changing device time is not available for apps on non-rooted devices. And it does not work for you because of this:

```
android:protectionLevel="signature|system"
```

which means only apps that are system apps or signed with system certificate are granted this permission. You are not.

Comment: So if I will remove this line of code from Manifest will it start working.If it is not , what are the changes required to do that?

Comment: Please suggest me. I am new in android.

Comment: No. You will not be granted this permission. You cannot change system time from your app.

Comment: Then any other solution please suggest me?  Which System App shall I use to change the Device time?

Comment: root the device. Or drop the idea.